# MongoDB aggregrate two collections on foreign key

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am attempting to pull data from my Mongo instance that will show all users for a given account Id. Users can be part of more than one account so I have currently got this structure for my Mongo models:

UserModel:

```
username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
```

UsersToAccountModel:

```
{
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users'
    },
    userGroup: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'userGroups'
    },
    account: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'accounts'
    },
    default: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: null
    }
}
```

The UsersToAccount model collection holds the ObjectId of the user, account, and userGroup in it's fields so is acting as a link collection as such.

For every userId that matches the given account ID in the UsersToAccount collection I want to take that ID and query the users table and return it. In MYSQL the query would be:

SELECT * FROM userToAccounts u2a LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = u2a.userId WHERE u2a.account = $accountId

Can anyone help me here?I have tired aggregation but I am not getting very far.

Here is my attempt so far which isn't working:

```
const users = await this.userToAccountModel.aggregate(
                {
                    $match:  { account: requestVars.account },
                },
                {
                    $lookup : { from: "users", localField: "_id", as: "userData", foreignField: "user"}
                }
            );
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) stage has the following syntax:

```
{
    $lookup: {
       from: <collection to join>,
       localField: <field from the input documents>,
       foreignField: <field from the documents of the "from" collection>,
       as: <output array field>
    }
}
```

So I think you need to swap the `localField` and `foreignField` values.

Secondly, [aggregate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) expect an array.

```
const users = await this.userToAccountModel.aggregate([
    {
        $match:  { account: requestVars.account },
    },
    {
        $lookup : { from: "users", localField: "user", foreignField: "_id", as: "userData" }
    }
]);
```